# XSLT newbie, replacing values

Tags: xml, xslt

My mistake, I make it clear:

I have a simple question, but I am new to XSLT:

I have 2 xml files:

**`usa1.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<country>
  <state name="CA">
    <city name="Sunnyvale" county="Sant Clara">
      <street number="123">
        El Comino Ave.
      </street>
    </city>
    <city name="San Jose" county="Sant Clara">
      <street number="345">
        De Anza Ave.
      </street>
    </city>
    <city name="palo Alto" county="Sant Clara">
      <street number="789">
        Shoreline Ave.
      </street>
    </city>

  </state>
</country>
```

**`usa2.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<country>
  <state name="CA">
    <city name="Sunnyvale" county="Sant Clara">
      <street number="999">
        Homestead Ave.
      </street>
    </city>
    <city name="San Jose" county="Sant Clara">
      <street number="888">
        Airport Ave.
      </street>
    </city>
  </state>
</country>
```

I want to use XSLT to replace all values and attributes of City  Sunnyvale and San Jose in `usa1.xml` with data from `usa2.xml`.

idea output as usa4.xml:

**`usa4.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<country>
  <state name="CA">
    <city name="Sunnyvale" county="Sant Clara">
      <street number="999">
        Homestead Ave.
      </street>
    </city>
    <city name="San Jose" county="Sant Clara">
      <street number="888">
        Airport Ave.
      </street>
    </city>
    <city name="palo Alto" county="Sant Clara">
      <street number="789">
        Shoreline Ave.
      </street>
    </city>

  </state>
</country>
```

How can I do this?

I tried the following XSLT, but the returned output is not what I was expecting:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:param name="usaxml" select="'usa1.xml'" />
  <xsl:variable name="address" select="document($usaxml)//" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:attribute name="number">
       <xsl:value-of select="$address/@street" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you need to do. If you replace all the values in the first file with those of the second one then the first file becomes identical to the second one - at that point you could simply use the second file directly...no need for XSLT

Comment: You can use usa1.xml as your source document, and `document("usa2.xml")` to access the XML in usa2.xml. I'm not sure if that's what you needed to know... the question is broad.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this transformation?  Do you want to replace the contents of `usa1.xml` with the contents of `usa2.xml` (which as @MiMo mentioned is a pointless exercise) or do you want to merge the two datasets?

Comment: usa1.xml after some time has added several elements, and usa1.xml and usa2.xml are in 2 diff places and become some diff, But after a few days, I need to use old values in usa2.xml to replace usa1.xml; that is conditions, I hope my explanation is clear?? thanks

Comment: "Do you want to replace the contents of usa1.xml with the contents of usa2.xml"For all matching elements, correct,

Comment: usa1.xml and usa2.xml some elements are same, some elements are diff. I only want the values of same elements in usa1.xml will be replaced by the values of same elements in usa2.xml

Comment: I believe he wants to replace the attributes and child elements of `<city>` elements in usa1.xml with those of the corresponding `<city>` in use2.xml (if one exists), where corresponding means that the `city/@name`s are the same, and the `city/parent::state/@name`s are also the same. +1 for posting an XSLT attempt, by the way.

Comment: LarsH, you are right, Could you pls post your solution??
thanks

Comment: There's a good question here with clear examples (clear to me, and i'm no xml expert) but the title could be improved.  I don't want to change it since I'm not so sure myself what it should be.  Perhaps "Updating info in one XML file with optional info from another, using XSLT" ?  Kinda long.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a key for the cross reference between the two files but admittedly the code becomes a bit convoluted with XSLT 1.0 if you need to use keys between documents:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="state/city" use="concat(../@name, '|', @name)"/>

<xsl:param name="usaxml" select="'test2013050302.xml'" />
<xsl:variable name="address" select="document($usaxml)" />

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="state/city">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$address">
      <xsl:variable name="ref-data" select="key('k1', concat($this/../@name, '|', $this/@name))"/>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$ref-data">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$ref-data/@* | $ref-data/node()"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$this/@* | $this/node()"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So with the primary input being

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<country>
  <state name="CA">
    <city name="Sunnyvale" county="Sant Clara">
      <street number="123">
        El Comino Ave.
      </street>
    </city>
    <city name="San Jose" county="Sant Clara">
      <street number="345">
        De Anza Ave.
      </street>
    </city>
    <city name="palo Alto" county="Sant Clara">
      <street number="789">
        Shoreline Ave.
      </street>
    </city>

  </state>
</country>
```

and the parameter file `test2013050302.xml` being

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<country>
  <state name="CA">
    <city name="Sunnyvale" county="Sant Clara">
      <street number="999">
        Homestead Ave.
      </street>
    </city>
    <city name="San Jose" county="Sant Clara">
      <street number="888">
        Airport Ave.
      </street>
    </city>
  </state>
</country>
```

the transformation result is

```
<country>
  <state name="CA">
    <city name="Sunnyvale" county="Sant Clara">
      <street number="999">
        Homestead Ave.
      </street>
    </city>
    <city name="San Jose" county="Sant Clara">
      <street number="888">
        Airport Ave.
      </street>
    </city>
    <city name="palo Alto" county="Sant Clara">
      <street number="789">
        Shoreline Ave.
      </street>
    </city>

  </state>
</country>
```

Using an XSLT 2.0 processor and XSLT 2.0 you could vastly simplify the template to

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="state/city" use="concat(../@name, '|', @name)"/>

<xsl:param name="usaxml" select="'test2013050302.xml'" />
<xsl:variable name="address" select="document($usaxml)" />

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="state/city">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:variable name="ref-data" select="key('k1', concat(../@name, '|', @name), $address)"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$ref-data">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$ref-data/(@*, node())"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Martin: great job, Thanks so much,